# java: how to send accelerator key

Tags: java, swing, jtable, junit4, keyboard-events

I am using Junit4 under eclipse. 
I would like to write a test which can be able to send the action : `ctrl+shift+P`

I tried this using JTable as I don't know for which component I could use the `sendAcceleratorKey` :

```
myTable.sendAcceleratorKey(InputEvent.CTRL, InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK)
```

but I can't add a third argument to say `KeyEvent.P`.

How can I send this action which changes the menu?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `sendAcceleratorKey()`? Are you looking for [`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28int,%20int%29)?

Comment: using KeyStroke.getKeyStroke , how could I use ctrl+shift+letterKey ? thanks

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can use the [Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);

Thread.sleep(1000); // Time for your code to react to the event

assert(...);

robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
```

Comment: aymeric , what's Robot class ? is it known class?

Comment: Robot class is part of the J2SE jdk. The full path is java.awt.Robot. Basically, it's used to simulate mouse clicks/moves, key events, ...

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any reference to `sendAcceleratorKey()`. But if it really exists and it does what you want, it looks logic to me to use the the method this way, using key modifiers:

```
myTable.sendAcceleratorKey(InputEvent.CTRL | InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK,
                           KeyEvent.VK_P);
```

Otherwise, try to swap the parameters, depending on the methods signature.

```
myTable.sendAcceleratorKey(KeyEvent.VK_P,
                           InputEvent.CTRL | InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);
```

Comment: otherwise what do you suggest ?

Comment: no, I mean is there another way to send accelerator ctrl+shift+letterKey ?

Comment: @lola: Try aymeric suggestion. It's `java.awt.Robot`. Very useful class! :D